# "× TypeError: this.props.tracks.map is not a function" why this happen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i try to pass information as props from a component to other component but i receive this message from the trackList component "TypeError: this.props.tracks.map is not a function" , please help me

```
This is my parent component App file:

import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import SearchResults from "../SearchResults/SearchResults";
import Playlist from "../Playlist/Playlist";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [{name:"songName1", artist:"ArtistName1", album:"Album1", id: 1}, 
      {name:"songName2", artist:"ArtistName1", album:"Album1", id: 2}, 
      {name:"songName3", artist:"ArtistName1", album:"Album1", id: 3}],
      playlistName: "My New Playlist",
      playlistTracks: [{name:"songName4", artist: "ArtistName4", album: "Album4", id: 4}, 
      {name:"songName5", artist: "ArtistName5", album: "Album5", id: 5}, 
      {name:"songName6", artist: "ArtistName6", album: "Album6", id: 6}]
    };
    this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
  }
  
addTrack (track) {
  let playlistTracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
  
  if (playlistTracks.find(trackin => trackin.id === track.id)) {
    return
  }
let newPlaylistTracks = playlistTracks.push(track);
   this.setState({
    playlistTracks: newPlaylistTracks
  })
   

}

render () {
  return (
   <div>
  <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
  <div className="App">
    {/*<SearchBar />*/}
    <div className="App-playlist">
      <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} onAdd={this.addTrack} />
      <Playlist playlistName={this.state.playlistName} playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks} />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

this is the searchResults file :

```
import React from "react";
import "./SearchResults.css";
import TrackList from "../TrackList/TrackList"

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="SearchResults">
              <h2>Results</h2>
              <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults} onAdd={this.props.onAdd} isRemoval={false} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default SearchResults;
```

this is the playlist file :

```
import React from "react";
import "./Playlist.css";
import TrackList from "../TrackList/TrackList";

class Playlist extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="Playlist">
              <input defaultValue={this.props.playlistName}/>
              <TrackList tracks={this.props.playlistTracks} isRemoval={true} />
              <button className="Playlist-save">SAVE TO SPOTIFY</button>
           </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Playlist;
```

this is the TrackList file :

```
import React from "react";
import "./TrackList.css";
import Track from "../Track/Track";


class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render () {
        
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.tracks.map((track) => { 
              return <Track track={track} key={track.id} onAdd={this.props.onAdd} isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval} />
            })}
         </div>
        )
    }
}
```

this is the track file :

```
import React from "react";
import "./Track.css";


class Track extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
  }

  
    renderAction () {
  if (this.props.isRemoval) {
    return <button > - </button>
  } else {
    return <button onClick={this.addTrack}> + </button>
  } 
       
    }
 
  addTrack () {
    this.props.onAdd(this.props.track);
  }
    render () {
        return (

            <div className="Track-action">
               <div className="Track-information">
                 <h3>{this.props.track.name}</h3>
                 <p>{this.props.track.artist} | {this.props.track.album}</p>
               </div>
              {this.renderAction()}
           </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Track;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason of Error

You are setting the playlist array with:

```
let newPlaylistTracks = playlistTracks.push(track);
```

However, `.push` returns the length of the array:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

console.log(arr.push(4))
```

#### Other Issues

You are mutating the state variables like:

```
let playlistTracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
  
playlistTracks.push(track); // NO! Mutation...
```

You should use a copy of the state variable to update it:

```
 this.setState({
    playlistTracks: [...this.state.playlistTracks, track]
  })
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend

Comment: Kindly consider accepting this as answer if it solved your problem :) Happy coding.